# What is the max limit of group_concat/string_agg in bigquery output?

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using **group_concat/string_agg** (possibly varchar) and want to ensure that bigquery won't drop any of the data concatenated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BigQuery will not drop data if a particular query runs out of memory; you will get an error instead. You should try to keep your row sizes below ~100MB, since beyond that you'll start getting errors. You can try creating a large string with an example like this:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(word) AS words FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`;
```

There are 164,656 rows in this table, and this query creates a string with 1,168,286 characters (around a megabyte in size). You'll start to see an error if you run a query that requires more than something on the order of hundreds of megabytes on a single node of execution, though:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(word, corpus)) AS words
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000));
```

This results in an error:

```
Resources exceeded during query execution.
```

If you click on the "Explanation" tab in the UI, you can see that the failure happened during stage 1 while building the results of `STRING_AGG`. In this case, the string would have been 3,303,599,000 characters long, or approximately 3.3 GB in size.

Comment: is there a way I can check what amount of data is being used by different nodes when processing the query (any report or something) like 'Explanation'?

Comment: You'll need to wait until the query completes, and then look at the "Explanation" tab, since the execution strategies may change as it's running.

Comment: I checked the explanation tab, it only gives the number of input and output rows and not node-wise data stats.

Comment: I was just pointing out that it will show where the failure was if the query runs out of memory. We don't show exact memory usage because usage and capacity is somewhat fluid and it wouldn't be meaningful to see in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to Elliot's answer - how to fix:

This query (Elliot's) fails:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(word, corpus)) AS words
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000));
```

But you can LIMIT the number of strings concatenated to get a working solution:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(word, corpus) LIMIT 10) AS words
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000));
```