# Can I catch out of memory errors when using STRING_AGG on BigQuery?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, string-aggregation

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196659/what-is-the-max-limit-of-group-concat-string-agg-in-bigquery-output) explains what happens when you try to aggregate too many things with STRING_AGG in BigQuery.

Is there a way I can do something like "Try STRING_AGG, but if it's too much data, return null (or something) instead"? So I can fallback from errors without the query failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [What is the max limit of group_concat/string_agg in bigquery output?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45196659/what-is-the-max-limit-of-group-concat-string-agg-in-bigquery-output) Elliott explains why STRING_AGG might produce out of memory errors.

To prevent this error, you can use LIMIT to stop aggregating after certain number of strings:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT STRING_AGG(CONCAT(word, corpus) LIMIT 10) AS words
FROM `bigquery-public-data.samples.shakespeare`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(GENERATE_ARRAY(1, 1000));
```